# Logistic Time Discrete Hazard Model Parameter Estimates Intrepration

Tags: sas

I am using PROC GLIMMIX, and I'm curious as to why my parameter estimates are behaving strangely.

```
proc glimmix data=blah pconv=1e-3;
class strata1;
model event(event=LAST)=time1--time20/
noint solution link=logit dist=binary;
nloptions tech=nrridg;
covtest 'var(strata1)=0'/WALD;
random intercept/subject=strata1;
run;
```

Since I'm using a logistic discrete time hazard model (without any censored observations), I have my dataset constructed using the 'person-period' dataset. Here is an example of what a person-period dataset looks like:

`id time1 time2 time3 time4 event
100 1 0 0 0 0
100 0 1 0 0 0
100 0 0 1 0 1
101 1 0 0 0 1
102 1 0 0 0 0
102 0 1 0 0 0
102 0 0 1 0 0
102 0 0 0 1 0`

Essentially, each 'time' variable represents whether this period is occuring. So, time1=1 during the first period, 0 otherwise. And then time2=1 during the first period, 0 otherwise, and so on. I am modelling the probability that the event occurs during each of these periods. When I use PROC LOGISITIC, I get sensible parameter estimates.

`proc logistic data=blah;
model event (event=LAST)=time1--time20 /noint;
run;`

This code delivers parameter estimates for time1=-3.0052, which gives me a probability of the event occuring in time period 1 of .047. These estimates slowly get smaller, for each time[i] variable, which is what I would expect. However, when I run my GLIMMIX code and add in this random effect for strata1, it blows up my model - the parameter estimates for time flip their sign. time1=2.84, time2=2.67, time3=2.41, and they consistently get smaller. I'm really confused as to why- this model is telling me that the probability of the event occuring is over 90% in this period, which I know to be untrue. Does anyone have any idea why this is? I would expect these estimates to essentially have their negative sign be flipped.

Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a question more about the code than the statistical issues. Why don't you ask SAS tech support, you're paying for it.

Comment: I have asked SAS, and they unfortunately have not provided any response to me. I was hoping someone here would have some insight.